# Azure Object Anchors - support photogrammetry generated models?

Tags: azure-object-anchors

Is Azure Object Anchors intended to work with reality captured/photogrammetry sourced 3D models (textured meshes) or just CAD models?

If AOA is intended to work with reality captured models, are there any additional considerations for pre-processing the models to be aware of?

Answer (score 2):

AOA depends on the geometry match of the object you are trying to detect. If the model is reality captured/ photogrammetry sourced, it will work as long as the outer shape matches that of the real world object.
There should no special considerations for pre-processing, make sure the dimensions of the model and real world are 1:1.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).